# Occasional false positive memory leak when using std::future and _CrtMemDifference on Windows

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, memory-leaks, stdasync

Below is a minimal repro of the memory leak I see when using std::future. Inside `ParallelForEach` I create an array of `std::future` with a subsequent `get` that should block the execution of the main thread until all the tasks for `vec` are finished. Once the function `ParallelForEach` returns, the vector of futures must be cleaned up. But building with debug and `_CrtMemDifference` I see an occasional memory leak which I suspect to be false positive and its just windows not cleaning up the threads in time until process exit.

```
Total bytes leaked: 49128
```

This is a problem since I have mem leak check in my tests that I don't want to get rid of. Why does this leak happen and how can I use both `_CrtMemDifference` and `std::future`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <future>
#include <crtdbg.h>

int func(int x) {
  return x * x;
}

void ParallelForEach(const std::vector<int>& vec) {
  std::vector<std::future<int>> futures;
  for (const auto& x : vec) {
    futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, func, x));
  }
  for (auto& f : futures) {
    f.get();
  }
}

void MemoryLeakTest()
{
  std::vector<int> vec(64, 12);

  _CrtMemState before;
  _CrtMemCheckpoint(&before);

  ParallelForEach(vec);

  _CrtMemState after;
  _CrtMemCheckpoint(&after);

  _CrtMemState leaked;
  if (_CrtMemDifference(&leaked, &before, &after) != 0) {
    std::cout << "Total bytes leaked: " << leaked.lTotalCount << std::endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
  {
    MemoryLeakTest();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I tried `std::for_each` with parallel execution and this works without mem leak, but is not available in all targeted systems. I expect there to be a way/workaround to use std::future without Crt reporting false memory leaks.

Comment: I guess the leak is not because windows doesn't clean the threads, but because `std::async` perhaps creates a thread pool or so. Also see this possibly related issue on GitHub: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/949